# Updating toolStripStatusLabel immediately

Tags: c#, multithreading, statusstrip, toolstripstatuslabel

I have a WinForms program that has a `button`, a `statusStrip`, and a `toolStripStatusLabel` in that `statusStrip`. If I click the button and this runs:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Test";

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

Then the `toolStripStatusLabel`'s text doesn't update until after the thread is done sleeping. How do I get it to update immediately, then sleep the thread?

Comment: Use `toolStripStatusLabel1.Update()` before the sleep.

Comment: @P.Kouvarakis I don't see any such method in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripstatuslabel(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Sorry, you are right.`ToolStripStatusLabel` is not a `Control`. You have to call `Update()` on the toolstrip itself (`statusStrip`?).

Comment: Ah, yes! That works! Thank you!

Comment: Or you can add `async` before void and use `await Task.Delay(5000)` to replace `Thread.Sleep(5000)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [P. Kouvarakis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6315982/p-kouvarakis) said, the solution was this:

```
toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Test";
statusStrip1.Update();
```

Answer (score 0):

My status label change wasn't showing at runtime when the status strip had Spring set to true. I set Spring to false and it began showing.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to  add the StatusStrip text label (as a child) ('cause you can't manipulate with the text of a parent component) like this:

[image: child component]

2. When you double-click on statusstrip component you will see the next

[image: 2ble click pic]

Do NOT add the text change code here, cause it will be refreshed only after a click on it (as you can see on the picture - statusStrip1_ItemClicked)
so, any statusStrip1.Update(); this.Update(); etc can't help you.

3. How to do it quickly. You can add the `if` where the target condition started
   like in this picture

[image: example "if"]

Answer (score -1):

```
toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Test";
Application.DoEvents();
```

Answer (score -1):

Last solution with `Application.DoEvents()` is the best. `Application.DoEvents()` must be appended to each StatusStrip change:

```
private void SetParseStatus(object sender, ParseStatusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    toolStripProgressBar1.Value = e.Percent;
    Application.DoEvents();
}
```

Comment: DoEvents has potential side affects.  You should avoid using it in most circumstances.

Comment: DoEvents() does indeed have strange and possibly serious side effects.  I'm fighting DoEvents() right now where the application freezes because of liberal usage of DoEvents().  Unrolling the troubles will be difficult, it's been a week and I'm just now getting close to the issue.